# TypeScript error: Property 'FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis' (TS2339)

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have setup App Check on my Vue / Firebase app.

To enable local development with App Check I am following the [intructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/debug-provider?hl=en&authuser=0).

And those instructions ask you to set a debug token like so:

```
self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;
initializeAppCheck(app, { /* App Check options */ });
```

But my app is written in TypeScript and it gives me this TypeScript error:

```
TS2339: Property 'FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to declare a global to get this working:

```
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
  var FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN: boolean | string | undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trouble implementing appcheck with Next.js the solution is to check if the window object is available:

```
let appCheck
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true
  appCheck = initializeAppCheck(firebaseApp, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(
      '6LejbHcmAAAAALSjJodOKUnmstPZ1KjhiraGWjFA'
    ),
  })
}
```

Even if you're importing and using these Firebase services on the client side, during the server-side rendering (SSR) process, Next.js will try to execute the import statements and hence run into the window is not defined error.